# SQL Server replication subscriptions marked as inactive

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2005

Is there any way to force SQL Server NOT to mark subscriptions as inactive, ever?

It happens sporadically when there are connection issues and I don't want to have to reinitialize the subscription every time.

Note, I'm not talking about the subscriptions being marked as expired...just as inactive.

We have retention set to 0 (infinite). I'd rather have a big distribution database than have to reinitialize a 15GB database to a subscriber over the WAN. Anyway, the real issue here is that they are getting marked as inactive within just a few hours sometimes...or sometimes a few days...it seems sporadic. Is there any way to tell WHY SQL decided in its wisdom to mark them inactive?

Comment: I'd try setting your min_distretention higher than 0. You didn't mention what your max was, but I suspect that the cleanup agent is cleaning up commands before they have a chance to get replicated to your disconnected subscriber. I typically set it to a day (i.e. 24, since min_distretention is in hours).

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can do that programatically using t-SQL and a sql agent job.

Basically, you have to query distribution..MSSubscriptions and check the status column value to be 0 (Inactive).

**Status of the subscription**:
0 = Inactive; 
1 = Subscribed; 
**2 = Active**

Below T-SQL Will help you :

```
-- Author: Kin Shah
-- Date: 4-1-2013
-- For dba.stackexchange.com
-- Good to find out 
-- publisher_id
-- publisher_db
-- publication_id
-- subscriber_id
-- subscriber_db
select * From distribution..MSsubscriptions

--- based on the above values, run below statement
--- this can be run using SQLAgent job

if exists (select 1 from distribution..MSsubscriptions where status = 0)
begin
UPDATE distribution..MSsubscriptions
SET STATUS = 2
WHERE publisher_id = '--publisher_id -- will be integer --' 
    AND publisher_db = '--publisher db name ---'
    AND publication_id = '--publication_id -- will be integer --'
    AND subscriber_id = '--subscriber_id -- will be integer ---'
    AND subscriber_db = '-- subscriber_db ---'
end
else
begin
print 'The subscription is not INACTIVE ... you are good for now .... !!'
end
```

Comment: that was a very useful command, Thank you very much @Kin :) I have one remark concerning this T-SQL script, what if we would like to pass directly the parameters in the where clause from the subscriptions that are inactive. How can we do that ?

Answer (score 2):

According to [The subscription fails to Sync with the Publisher and marked inactive even though the settings have been configured to “never expire”](https://web.archive.org/web/20151001231713/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2008/10/04/did-you-know-the-subscription-fails-to-sync-with-the-publisher-and-marked-inactive-even-though-the-settings-have-been-configured-to-never-expire.aspx):

> In order to find the cause of deactivation we need to check the Transaction Retention period in the Distribution properties. If it is
> set to a lower number like 3 hours, then this indicates that if the
> subscriber does not synchronies in 3 hours, the distribution cleanup
> agent will truncate the commands tables in distribution and hence the
> subscriber will be marked as deactivated.
>
> Since the commands are deleted from distributor there is no other
> option but to reinitialize the subscriber.
>
> Also to find the cause of the Distributor not being able to sync we
> can check the Distribution history in the below tables on distribution
> database,
>
> msdistribution_agents
>
> msdistribution_history

In addition, from [Subscription Expiration and Deactivation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/subscription-expiration-and-deactivation?view=sql-server-ver15) in the product documentation:

> It is possible to specify that subscriptions never expire (a value of 0 for @retention), but it is strongly recommended that you do not use this value, because metadata cannot be cleaned up.

Also please read this MSDN forum thread about possible solutions:[Automatically mark inactive subscriptions for reinitialization](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506171527/http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab2b2dd0-2187-44dc-90bf-9e983f6634ea/automatically-mark-inactive-subscriptions-for-reinitialization?forum=sqlreplication)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version of the script in [Kin's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/38999) that I modified to run interactive in case anyone finds that helpful:

```
    --===================================
    -- please note that this should NOT be done in production
    --
    -- there is likely to be data loss, as we know we lost track of some rows in distribution.
    --===================================

    -- run on replication source having issue

    select *
        from distribution..MSsubscriptions sub
        WHERE publisher_id = sub.publisher_id
            AND publisher_db = sub.publisher_db
            AND publication_id = sub.publication_id
            AND subscriber_id = sub.subscriber_id
            AND subscriber_db = sub.subscriber_db
        and status = 0

    if exists (select 1 from distribution..MSsubscriptions where status = 0)
    begin
        begin tran
            UPDATE distribution..MSsubscriptions
            SET STATUS = 2
            from distribution..MSsubscriptions sub
            WHERE publisher_id = sub.publisher_id
                AND publisher_db = sub.publisher_db
                AND publication_id = sub.publication_id
                AND subscriber_id = sub.subscriber_id
                AND subscriber_db = sub.subscriber_db
            and status = 0
        -- if you do not believe in paranoia checks, then comment out the following roll back
        rollback -- the default is set to 'roll back' to force DBA to manual run lines in this script
        commit
    end
    else
    begin
        print 'No subscriptions are INACTIVE ... you are good for now .... !!'
    end
```