# sql server - NoSync subscriptions will need to be dropped and recreated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, transactional-replication

I am having this error message from the sql server replication monitor:

> Error messages: The subscription(s) have been marked inactive and must
>   be reinitialized. NoSync subscriptions will need to be dropped and
>   recreated. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 21074) Get help:
>   http://help/21074

[image]

The publication is SupplierDB.

I have just generated an snapshot, as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

I have followed the answers and comments and not sure what else,
my subscription is now working, however, it shows up twice now, and I can't find a way to get rid of the one that is not working.

[image]

I got it double for some reason.
[image]

Comment: You have to query `distribution..MSSubscriptions` and check the status column value to be 0 (Inactive). Check my answer [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/38999/8783)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the registry of the Subcriber

here you will see the actual status

```
select * from [Publish_Database]..syssubscriptions
```

here the update for all articles subscribes

```
update [Publish_Database]..syssubscriptions set status=2 where srvname='server'
```

After that the snapshot should become effective again