# Determine when subscription became inactive in transactional replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, transactional-replication

When I try to send a tracer token on some of my publications to get the latency I get the following error -

> No active subscriptions were found. The publication must have active
>   subscriptions in order to post a tracer token.

There are subscriptions tied to these publications as well. I can fix this by re-initializing\rebuilding replication, but I was wondering if there is a way to tell with when the subscription stopped receiving anything? I want to determine how long this has not been working.

The tables that are being replicated do not have timestamps on them that allow me to figure it out based on that. I have checked Replication Monitor, navigated through several of the tables in the distribution database, checked the job history and SQL logs and not able to determine this. Is there a timestamp recorded somewhere that shows the last synch from the distributor to the subscriber?

We are using SQL Transactional Replication (Push) and on SQL Server 2012 SP4.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you setup a Replication Canary process, in line with the recommendations from Brent's blog: [monitoring-sql-server-transactional-replication](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/07/monitoring-sql-server-transactional-replication/).

We have created our own variation of this:

1. Make sure your Publisher and Subscriber servers have their clocks
   synced
2. Create a table for each publication that is going to hold a
   single row with structure

Sample script:

```
CREATE TABLE [{Schema}].[{PublicationName}_Canary]
( 
  [ID] INT NOT NULL, 
  [PublicationDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_{PublicationName}_Canary] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
    [ID] ASC
  )WITH (ONLINE = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO 

INSERT INTO [{Schema}].[{PublicationName}_Canary]
  (ID, PublicationDate)
VALUES (1, SYSUTCDATETIME())
```

3. Create a job that will update the single row on an interval, I like to use something that runs every few seconds, ie: 7 seconds (causes the canary to go through at odd times so we are more likely to spot scheduled actions that might get missed if the interval is too wide/synced to miss the Canary)
4. Add this Table to your publication
5. On the Subscriber create a table to log the canaries and when they arrive (don't forget to create a cleanup process to get rid of old data!)

Sample script:

```
CREATE TABLE [{Schema}].[Replication_Canary_Log]
( 
  [Publication] SYSNAME NOT NULL, 
  [PublicationDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
  [SubscriberDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

6. Alter your update stored procedure for that Canary article to insert into your `[Replication_Canary_Log]` when the update arrives on the Subscriber

Sample script:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_MSupd_{Schema}{PublicationName}_Canary]     
    @c1 int = NULL, @c2 DATETIME = NULL, @pkc1 int = NULL, @bitmap binary(1)
AS
begin   
    /* I've removed the main body of the replication stored procedure for brevity */

    /* Customization of this Replication proc to log every time an update arrives */
    DECLARE 
        @SubscriberDate DATETIME2 = SYSUTCDATETIME(), 
        @Publication SYSNAME = '{PublicationName}'

    INSERT INTO [{Schema}].[Replication_Canary_Log]
        ([Publication], [PublicationDate], [SubscriberDate])
    VALUES
        (@Publication , @PublicationDate, @SubscriberDate)
end 
GO
```

---

Having done all of the above, you now just need to monitor the latest rows in your `[{Schema}].[Replication_Canary_Log]` table to track when you have latency...  If your publication stops writing to a subscriber for any reason you will get a spike in latency (time since the last Canary arrived).  For us this then allows us to find out why:

- Network blip
- Bulk change to a replication table that's taking a long time to apply
- Subscriber has been marked as inactive and needs resyncing
- any other reason..

Answer (score 0):

You have to look into error log or job history (provided its not purged or recycled).

See my answer for T-Rep .. how to activate the subscription : https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/38999/8783

Comment: Thanks. Yeh, anything from the history is gone. From the few tables we do have timestamps on we have found that have not been replicating for months. Also, strangely I checked the status in MSsubscriptions before and nothing showed inactive. Everything was active or subscribed. However, when I sent a tracer token it said it was. When I opened it up in Replication Monitor it told me I needed to reinitialize the subscription.