# Resynchronize transactional replication in SQL Server 2012 without doing a complete reinitialization after disk filled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transactional-replication

We have a DB that is doing a transactional replication to one other server. There are three tables it is replicating in the DB. Yesterday the subscriber ran out of disk space. This caused the replication to fail. I tried to start it back up but the subscription failed with the error message

> Invalid object name 'MSreplication_subscriptions'.

Currently the subscription is sitting in a "running" status, but states

> The initial snapshot for publication <XXXXXX> is not yet available.

Is my *only* solution to reinitialize the subscription? I'm trying to avoid that if at all possible since the DB is quite large and our pipe isn't that large.

Comment: is the subscription expired ? If yes, then you have to reinit it.

Comment: @Kin its not "expired". This publication in the properties --> "General" page "Subsriptions never expire, but they can be deactivated until they are reinitialized." So I assume that it was "deactivated" automatically due to the crash/drive filling up?

Comment: Can you check using this script - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/38999/8783 `select * from distribution..MSsubscriptions where status = 0`

Comment: @Kin It is empty. No rows returned.

Comment: Did you do something else with the subscription DB? The transactions should be kept in the transaction log from the publisher, should just be a matter of restart the distribution agent again, which seems not the case.

Comment: @dbamex I did not do anything. There are several records with a status of 1 or 2 that could be the replication.