# One or more subscriptions have been marked inactive. Drop and re-create all subscriptions for this node that are failing with this error

Tags: sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

We have a production server error causing replication agent got failed and subscription became inactive. When I tried to restart synchronizing process, it is getting failed.

Should I delete/drop the current subscription and recreate the subscription again? or does Reinitialize subscription work? 
As you can see from the picture, replication from A to C is failed. How can I recteate the subscription of A from C?

Thanks
Subin[image]

Comment: HI Marcello, the error is mentioned in the title itself and it is a MSSQLError. "One or more subscriptions have been marked inactive. Drop and re-create all subscriptions for this node that are failing with this error" Event ID: 14151

Comment: check [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/33801/22336)